# Error in Filtering the lines which matches a word in a log file using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My goal is to frame an rdd with the error messages in the log file.
I am reading the log file and filtering the lines which matches the word "ERROR" and i need to write the error message to the database by framing it as a RDD.

I am new to spark

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.text( "hdfs://10.90.3.78:9000/user/centuryuidt-3-1-1.out")
val patt: String = "ERROR"
val rdd=df.filter(line => line.contains(patt)).collect()
df.foreach(println)
```

and i am getting the below exception while i execute this code.

```
<console>:40: error: value contains is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
       val rdd=df.filter(line => line.contains(patt)).collect()
                                      ^
<console>:43: error: overloaded method value foreach with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])Unit <and>
  (f: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => Unit)Unit
 cannot be applied to (Unit)
       df.foreach(println)
          ^
```

screenshot:

[image: error screenshot]

Adding Few changes,

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val lines = sc.textFile( "hdfs://10.90.3.78:9000/user/centuryuidt-3-1-1.out")
val error = lines.filter(_.contains("ERROR"))
val df = error.toDF()
```

This worked for me but i need to frame a DF with rows, It just gave me the all the error lines in a single row.
can any one help me out to split the lines in to rows.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my complete example:

```
scala> val df = spark.read.text("errors.txt")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df.show
+------+
| value|
+------+
|line 1|
| ERROR|
|line 2|
| ERROR|
+------+


scala> val errors = df.filter(row => row.getString(0).contains("ERROR"))
errors: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [value: string]

scala> errors.collect.foreach(println)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
```

If you really need errors as an RDD - note this is an RDD[Row]:

```
scala> errors.rdd
res7: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[13] at rdd at <console>:34
```

If you really need errors as an RDD[String]:

```
scala> errors.map(_.getString(0)).rdd
res9: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[19] at rdd at <console>:34
```

Comment: Nope i am facing the below error,   <console>:29: error: value getString is not a member of String
       val filtered = lines.filter(row => row.getString(0).contains("ERROR"))
                                              ^

Comment: I have added a complete example above. This works in Spark 2.3. It also works if I use an SQLContext instance instead of SparkSession. Note if you need an RDD with the error column then just call errors.rdd

Comment: Thanks for the code and clear explanation. It works good. IF in case i need to print the next two lines along with the error line then what i need to change in this code.? kindly help me in this scenario. - Thanks.